# specifying probability distribution in julia

Tags: julia

R user here (with no Julia knowledge). Trying to use the bigsimr.jl package in R. Can anyone direct me to how to specify a custom probability distribution compatible with Distributions.jl? Specifically, I want to specify the Poisson lognormal distribution as a marginal probability distribution. Thanks